# $(function() { Get error: is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code and i get "TypeError: $ is not a function".

I have copied straight from this tut: http://jsfiddle.net/livibetter/HV9HM/

this is the website im working on: http://www.vetlesen.no

```
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
    }
}
```

This is the error

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

-

```
var dir = 1;
var MIN_TOP = 200;
var MAX_TOP = 350;

function autoscroll() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop() + dir;
    if (window_top >= MAX_TOP) {
        window_top = MAX_TOP;
        dir = -1;
    } else if (window_top <= MIN_TOP) {
        window_top = MIN_TOP;
        dir = 1;
    }
    $(window).scrollTop(window_top);
    window.setTimeout(autoscroll, 100);
}
```

Comment: You need to reference JQuery. JS Fiddles don't show external references in the code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus He did, but `$` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to write on top of your sticky.js

```
    var $ = jQuery;
```

Seems something wrong with your jquery initialization (jquery doesnt initialized the $ var in global space)

Comment: Do you know why its not possible to change whats inside the sticky <div>?
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky">HERE</div>

Comment: It should be possible with `$('#sticky').text('some custom text')`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Wordpress. In Wordpress [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) is called on the jQuery file it includes (scroll to the bottom of the file it's including for jQuery to see this), **which means `$` doesn't work**, but `jQuery` does.

If you dont want to be bothered to change the syntax you can use

```
let $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

This error defines you did not have your JQuery script loaded.
Make sure you have added JQuery script to your web page.

Comment: seems that jquery is on the page but with .noConflict() methods called